Iceberg table not listing all snapshots (python)
Question
Hello, I have a question regarding iceberg table snapshots. I used pyiceberg to create a namespace and a table, then insert a dataframe like so:
from pyiceberg.catalog import load_rest
from pyiceberg.schema import Schema
from pyiceberg.types import StringType, NestedField, DoubleType
from pyiceberg.partitioning import PartitionSpec, PartitionField
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows = 10**1
ncols = 10
countries = ["US", "CA", "UK"]
attr2 = ["OPEN", "CLOSE", "LOW", "HIGH"]
dates = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31")
data_orig = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "countries": countries[i % len(countries)],
            "status": attr2[i % len(attr2)],
            "return_index": np.random.rand(),
        }
        for i in range(rows)
    ]
)

schema = Schema(
    NestedField(field_id=1, name="countries", field_type=StringType(), required=False),
    NestedField(field_id=2, name="status", field_type=StringType(), required=False),
    NestedField(
        field_id=3, name="return_index", field_type=DoubleType(), required=False
    ),
)
partition_spec = PartitionSpec(
    fields=[
        PartitionField(
            source_id=1, field_id=1000, name="countries", transform="identity"
        ),
        PartitionField(source_id=2, field_id=1001, name="status", transform="identity"),
    ]
)
catalog = load_rest(
    "rest",
    conf={
        "uri": "http://localhost:19120/iceberg",
    },
)
catalog.create_namespace_if_not_exists("rpmd")
tables = catalog.list_tables(namespace="rpmd")

table = catalog.create_table_if_not_exists(
    identifier="rpmd.performance", schema=schema, partition_spec=partition_spec
)
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

tbl = pa.Table.from_pandas(data_orig)
table.append(tbl)


When i run this script a second time, it is my understanding that the append method would create a new commit, and in turn, a new snapshot of the rpmd.performance iceberg table, and i should be able to see a list of snapshots in the latest metadata.json file. However, i only see the latest snapshot in the array, and running table.inspect.snapshots() only shows 1 snapshot_id, even though i see all the relevant .avro files.
May i know if there is some configuration i need to do to ensure that i can see all snapshots?
For some additional background information, in the latest metadata.json file, this is how the snapshots section look like:
"snapshots": [
        {
            "sequence-number": 3,
            "snapshot-id": 1182955948280775518,
            "timestamp-ms": 1724830740048,
            "summary": {
                "operation": "append",
                "added-files-size": "82710797",
                "added-data-files": "12",
                "added-records": "10000000",
                "changed-partition-count": "12",
                "total-data-files": "32",
                "total-delete-files": "0",
                "total-records": "10000020",
                "total-files-size": "82740483",
                "total-position-deletes": "0",
                "total-equality-deletes": "0"
            },
            "manifest-list": "s3://tablestore-bucket/rpmd/performance_7fab8ae5-29b9-48cf-9cf2-b8c36478653f/metadata/snap-1182955948280775518-0-39fe1f0d-8c8f-4f4d-9fbf-1fd74b0a52cf.avro",
            "schema-id": 0
        }
    ],

the sequence number is being tracked correctly but only the latest snapshot is being saved. my understanding is that all the past snapshots should be saved.
